# Find out what type of unit is being used

Tags: geolocation, units

I'd like to know what type of unit is being used in this example to set extents, for the user to only be able to move in France's map. 
[example is here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/extent-constrained.html)

And the code is:

```
const view = new View({
  center: [328627.563458, 5921296.662223],
  zoom: 8,
  extent: [-572513.341856, 5211017.966314, 916327.095083, 6636950.728974],
});
```

As I said earlier, I'd like to know what type of unit is being used on the property `extent`, and if possible, know what numbers I should put into `extent` to create some sort of `square` that will allow the user to move only in the UK. 
I have this editable code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jygaf2?file=index.js,index.html), in case anyone wants to see it live.

Comment: Have a look at the CRS.

Comment: @Erik what would CRS be?

Comment: The coordinate reference system, which tells your unknown software how to interpret the coordinates.

Comment: Center and extent coordinates are in Web Mercator (Pseudo-Mercator) projection, CRS code is EPSG:3857 (see https://epsg.io/3857). Since this CRS is valid for the whole world, it can be used for UK too.

Comment: Except Pseudo-Mercator is also pseudo-meters, not actual meters, so the units might as well be "units".

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/):

> All coordinates and extents need to be provided in view projection
> (default: EPSG:3857). To transform coordinates from and to geographic,
> use fromLonLat() and toLonLat(). For extents and other projections,
> use transformExtent() and transform().

[EPSG:3857](https://epsg.io/3857) uses metres as the horizontal unit.  But note that this projected coordinate system is used for rendering maps in Google Maps, OpenStreetMap, etc and has no use outside of web mapping. i.e don't use it for any distance or area analyses or measurements.

Comment: Yah I won't. I am just trying to create the same type of thing showed in the example but surrounding UK instead, but I can't get the correct values.